# How to delay the LostFocus Event in VB6

Tags: vb6

I'm having an issue with a process that involves the `LostFocus` event.

When the cursor loses focus from a particular textbox, I'm simply putting the focus back into that box.

My issue is removing focus long enough for the user to click a log out button. Is there a way to intercept the `LostFocus` event long enough to allow the user to click the log out button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously I don't know the big picture here.  But keeping only with what you said, the following does the trick.  Effectively the event is delayed briefly, allowing the button to be clicked:

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Private Sub Text1_LostFocus()
   Sleep 100
   DoEvents

   Text1.SetFocus
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, sir! I'm so glad you're around to help!! Thanks again, Brian!

Comment: Hmmm.. Brian, I am getting Sub or Function not defined. Is there a reference I'm missing?

Comment: Don't forget to add the `Private Declare` sub, either in the form or in a module.  If in a module, make sure it is Public.

Comment: Brian, I added the entire block you have there, only changing my textbox name, but I now get this error: `Only comments may appear after End Sub, End Function or End Property`. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Make sure the `Private Declare` sub is at the very top of your file, right after `Option Explicit`.

Comment: Brian, I'm sorry to bother you again, but Sleep doesn't seem to be giving me the desired effect. I have the time set to 1000 (1 second). When I press the button, I can see that it allows me 1 second to do this, and I can see the button depressing, however, the click event isn't firing.

Comment: See my updated code.  I added a line to `DoEvents`.

Comment: Brian, that is working fine now, thank you! Question: The button the user will be clicking (the event that wasn't firing) is the Logout button. After running your code, I am getting the same form reload instead of unloading it and returning to the login form. Are these 3 commands correct to unload the current frmTest and reload the frmLogin? `frmtest.Hide Unload frmtest frmLogin.Show`

Comment: That's what I was afraid of... the "Big Picture".  You are hiding frmTest but after the delay you are trying to set focus to a control on frmTest.  At best this design isn't logically sound.  Since this is really a separate issue, I would suggest starting a new question.

Comment: Thanks Brian, I'll just ask a new question. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

With a combination of a `Timer` and another control that is outside of the borders of your form, you can achieve this.

```
Private Sub Text1_LostFocus()
    Combo1.SetFocus
    ReturnFocusTimer.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub ReturnFocusTimer_Timer()
    ReturnFocusTimer.Enabled = False
    Text1.SetFocus
End Sub
```

In this example `Combo1` is positioned beyond the bottom of the form. You can control the `ReturnFocusTimer` interval to however long you need.