# VB6: How do I force the cursor into a textbox but release for button press

Tags: vb6

I asked a similar question here: [How to delay the LostFocus Event in VB6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58736945/how-to-delay-the-lostfocus-event-in-vb6). It was suggested to use `DoEvents`, which didn't work for me because it was reloading all my forms.

What I need to do is to force the cursor into a textbox for a barcode read. However, I need to allow the user the ability to click 1 of 3 buttons on the form. So, what needs to happen is, possibly on hover over one of these buttons, release the cursor long enough to click a button.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way of accomplishing what you need.  In the button `Click` events, do the needed work and then `SetFocus` back to the textbox.  You will not respond to the `LostFocus` event as in the previous post.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Text1_LostFocus()
   'do nothing
End Sub

Private Sub Command1_Click()
   'do your work

   Text1.SetFocus
End Sub

Private Sub Command2_Click()
   'do your work

   Text1.SetFocus
End Sub

Private Sub Command3_Click()
   'do your work

   Text1.SetFocus
End Sub
```

Keep in mind that the textbox won't gain focus until the work is complete.

Comment: Be aware that if the bar code data arrives while the button click is doing it's work, then you'll likely lose that data.  The longer the click event code runs, the chance of this occurring goes up.  As long as your click event doesn't have much to do and runs quick, you'll probably be ok and won't lose data (no guarantee, however).